# create HBox component with default values

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I want to create an HBox component; for example HLBox that behaves exactly like an HBox but has as default width and height 100%.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `HLBox.mxml` file and add the following code to it.

```
<!-- HLBox.mxml -->
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

And use `HLBox` as you would use `HBox`

```
<HLBox>  
   <!-- Don't specify width or height attributes to HLBox tag, 
      it will overwrite the default ones -->
   <mx:Label text="something"/>
   <!-- other children -->
</HLBox>
```